# どこのコードが間違っているのかが分かりません

Tags: python, python3

NameError: name 'label' is not defined

**ソースコード:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキスト（マークダウン）で記入しましょう。

Answer (score 4):

typoですね。`print_info`の中の`format`の最初のパラメータで`self`と`label`の間が`.`(ドット)ではなく`,`(カンマ)になっています。